# Passing values with the UIHint to the View

Tags: c#-3.0, asp.net-mvc-2

With the UIHint you can also store some data on the model so you can react with that in the View. The Sintax as described in some blogs is:

```
[UIHint("TemplateToUse",null,"Variable1", "Value1", "Variable2", "Value2", ...)]
public string Something { get; set; }
```

---

And then I try to access this on the View with ViewData.ModelMetaData.AditioanlValues but the array returns empty!

Anyone have implemented this already to give me a "Hint" on how to use UIHint for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this out:
http://www.mikevdm.com/BlogEntry/Key/Using-UIHint-With-ControlParameters-in-MVC

Comment: Just a link is a bad answer, without context of what the link is about and where it goes etc. This is worse as the link gives a 404.

Answer (score 4):

As of MVC3 you can use the `AdditionalMetadataAttribute`

```
[AdditionalMetadata("Source", "ThisIsACustomValue")]
```

which is then accessed in the view as

```
ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["Source"];
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.additionalmetadataattribute(v=vs.98).aspx